# text is not a function error using event.target

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is wrong here?

I'm expecting `5` in console.

```js
function fn(event){
let obj = event.target;
let x = parseInt(obj.text());
console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent' oncontextmenu = 'return false'>
<div class = 'title' oncontextmenu = 'fn(event)'>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you think there's a property named `text` and that it's a function?

Comment: unless you do `let obj = $(event.target);`, `.text()` is jquery, `.text` is vanilla. This is a good reason not to mix them up

Comment: Yes, didn't notice this was a div

Comment: I dont think .text() is a javascript method

Comment: Out of interest, where can I find some documentation on `Element.text`?

Comment: @OliverRadini There's none, `text` is an own property of [option element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement) and [script element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement), though.

Comment: @Teemu great, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments are useful but don't give you an exact answer. `text` is not a function on a DOM element, but `textContent` is a property of DOM elements which you can use:

```js
function fn(event){
  let obj = event.target;
  let x = parseInt(obj.textContent);
  console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent' oncontextmenu = 'return false'>
<div class = 'title' oncontextmenu = 'fn(event)'>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to get `obj` as jquery object?

Comment: @qadenza Just use `$(obj)`

Comment: @qadenza yes indeed, as Terry suggests